# Custom delegate method not called 100

Tags: objective-c, delegates

I am trying to use custom delegate between NSObject class and UIViewController class. delegate is declared in NSObject method as

```
 @protocol MYDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)methodOne;
 @end

@property(nonatomic,strong) id <MYDelegate> delegate;
```

and trying to call it by

```
if([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(methodOne)]){
    [delegate methodOne];
}
```

method is defined in ViewController class as

```
UIViewController <MYDelegate>

-(void)methodOne{
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"someScreenSegue" sender:self];
}
```

Not getting what I am missing here. delegate method is not getting called ever. I am getting `self->delegate:
<nil>`
Delegate is returning nil always

Comment: You need to set the `delegate` property to the class that implements the `methodOne` method.

Comment: 1. You have never assigned a value to `delegate`. 2. You declare a protocol `MYDelegate` and then try to use a protocol `HDGetGmailInfoDelegate`.

Comment: sorry By mistake I missed that in my code. I am also setting value to delegate in viewController method like  getGmailInfo = [[HDGetGmailInfo alloc] init];
    getGmailInfo.delegate = self; HDGetGmailInfo is my NSObject Class where I have declared delegate

Answer (score 1):

Delegates is call back mechanism. When you want to use a delegate you have to do the following:

1. Create the delegate protocol (which you did)
2. Have the class that implements the call back, implement the protocol (which you did)
3. Connect the delegate from the calling class to self to allow the call-back to happen (this is missing).

So you need somewhere in your code to assign the delegate property.

Comment: I am setting delegate in class where i have defined its methods getGmailInfo = [[HDGetGmailInfo alloc] init]; getGmailInfo.delegate = self

Comment: Can you detail your question? You have 1 View Controller which implements the delegate. Who is the class that needs the call back? What is the flow?

Comment: Where are you setting the delegate in your viewController? Maybe it's happening somewhere in your viewController life cycle that happens after you're trying to access the delegate.

Comment: I have one class where I have written the delegate. And other is viewController class. where I have implemented the Delegate methods. first class should respond to the methods defined in the viewController class when it finishes its task using respondsToSelector

Comment: Yes I am setting delegate in ViewController class. in ViewDidLoad method

Comment: Well, it does look like it's alright with your viewController implementation. You could try putting a breakpoint inside your viewDidLoad method to check if it's alright with the init of your HDGetGmailInfo object. Maybe it's nil when you assign it to your delegate property.

Comment: Well, that's odd. So, right after you assign your viewController (self) as the delegate for your HDGetGmailInfo object, everything is fine. Where do you get the error message that the delegate is nil?